# How do I make a substitution to `$0` but save the old value?

Tags: bash, command-line, awk, grep

I'm trying to rename all files that start with an "m" to be the same name except with the first character (or "m" in this case) stripped away.

My strategy is to:

1. List all the files, with `ls`
2. Filter for the ones I want, with `egrep`
3. Generate the string I don't want next to the one I want, separated by a space, with `awk`, for example, `mfoo foo`
4. Feed into `xargs` to `mv mfoo foo`

Some questions:

- Is this a good strategy?
- What is a better one?

I'm stuck on Step 3, below is how I've approached the problem.

I'm working in the following directory:

```
$ find .
.
./cat
./mbar
./mbaz
./mfoo
```

I'm able to quickly get 1-2:

```
$ ls | egrep '^m'
mbar
mbaz
mfoo
```

Step 3 is more difficult. I used `gsub` to generate the second string I want, but I'm not sure how to "stick it together with the original value separated by a space":

```
$ ls | egrep '^m' | awk '{ gsub(/^./, ""); print }'
bar
baz
foo
```

Step 4 by it's makes sense to me, although I'm not sure how to finish Step 3 so I can't finish it yet. Below is one example of how I think it should work:

```
$ echo mfoo foo | xargs mv
$ find .
.
./cat
./foo
./mbar
./mbaz
```

I think I'm close I just need to find out how to save the old value and print it next to the gsubed value. I've tried the following small example but it's not working:

```
$ echo mfoo | awk '
pipe quote> { old = $0 }
pipe quote> { new = gsub(/^./, "") }
pipe quote> { print $old " " $new }'
awk: illegal field $(mfoo), name "old"
 input record number 1, file
 source line number 4
```

- How do I make a substitution to `$0` but save the old value?
- Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ls | egrep '^m' | awk '{ x=$0; gsub(/^./, ""); $0 = x " " $0 }1' | xargs -l -t mv
```

Posix-*ly* implementation is via the `-L` option to `xargs` as:

```
ls | egrep '^m' | awk '{ x=$0; gsub(/^./, ""); $0 = x " " $0 }1' | xargs -L 1 -t mv

ls | egrep '^m' | awk '{ x=$0; gsub(/^./, ""); print x, $0 }' | xargs -L 1 -t mv
```

Based on what [I replied](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/358006/173557) to your earlier query regarding `xargs`, we can put that learning to good use in this example.

I slightly modified your `awk` code: it preserves the original line (`$0`) since the `gsub` func is gonna clobber it. Then we put together the old & the new to get the line we want to send over to `xargs` which will then invoke `mv` with the right arguments to effect the rename.

Comment: What does the `1` (one)  at the end of your `awk` program do?

Comment: `1` will print the current line (`$0`) after all the modifs have happened. I've added an alternative to the `1` in the Answer section, you may want to check.

Comment: @mbigras awk's default action for a true condition is to print `$0`, so many awk commands end with a `1` as a shortcut to printing the line.

Comment: Note that this is only an acceptable solution if you don’t care about your data. Since you like learning experiences I’ll let you figure out (or discover) why :-).

Comment: Just for the record, gnu xargs man pages in Debian refers that -l option is deprecated and -L should be used instead :https://manpages.debian.org/testing/findutils/xargs.1.en.html

Answer (score 8):

This should handle the whole operation:

```
for file in m*; do mv "${file}" "${file#m}"; done
```

Before you run that, check things first with

```
for file in m*; do echo mv "${file}" "${file#m}"; done
```

This uses the `m*` glob for steps 1 and 2, then `${file#m}` (which removes “m” from the beginning of `${file}`) for step 3, and finally a loop for step 4.

To answer your AWK question, you could go about it this way:

```
echo mfoo | awk '{ print $0, substr($0, 2) }'
```

AWK variables don’t use `$`, that’s just for fields; that’s where your error is coming from: AWK understands `$old` as “the value of the field numbered  according to the value of `old`”. It’s easier to read too if you place your commands in a single block (assuming they have the same pattern). Fixing your script gives

```
echo mfoo | awk '{ old = $0; gsub(/^./, ""); print old, $0 }'
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! Do you think it's not a good strategy to break up the tasks using separate programs and stick them together as part of a pipeline? I like it better because it's easier for me to think about. Also is this not a good time to use `awk`? I'm learning how to use it so I was excited to use it but I also thought it was an appropriate time to use it.

Comment: Breaking up tasks is a good strategy, but you need to use the appropriate tools (and learning about all the tools is a never-ending task...). Parsing `ls`’s output is [not a good idea](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/86440), and using AWK for simple string processing is overkill.

Comment: But do you think learning bash substring removal is worth it? The first line of the [bash scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html): `Bash supports a surprising number of string manipulation operations. Unfortunately, these tools lack a unified focus. Some are a subset of parameter substitution, and others fall under the functionality of the UNIX expr command. This results in inconsistent command syntax and overlap of functionality, not to mention confusion.` It seems like starting off by just learning `awk` and `sed` for string manipulation is a better idea, no?

Comment: Yes, I think it’s worth it, for two reasons. The first is that using another process has a cost (which can be amortised by running a single process over a stream of data). The second, and main reason is that passing strings around from the shell to other processes and back involves parsing those strings, and losing information about them.

Answer (score 2):

A better strategy is to use the `rename` command.

Note that the exact syntax of this commands is distro specific, consult the `man` page of your particular version of distro. On Ubuntu, for example, which has a Perl implementation of `rename`, you can use a regex:

```
rename -nono 's/^m//' m*
```

Note: remove the `-nono` flag to actually perform the renaming.

Comment: If it's `prename` then just `-n` would do...

Comment: Yes, this is the best way to solve the original problem.